# Text-align in left in boxlayout

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## user.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import CoreImage kivy.core.image.Image
#:import os os

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

1. How to add background color of user list
2. How to shift in left align

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Text Alignment - Button/Label

By default the text image (texture) is only just large enough to contain the characters and is positioned in the center. The valign property will have no effect and halign will only have an effect if your text has newlines; a single line of text will appear to be centered even though halign is set to left (by default).

In order for the alignment properties to take effect, set the text_size, which specifies the size of the bounding box within which text is aligned. For instance, the following code binds this size to the size of the Button/Label, so text will be aligned within the widget bounds. This will also automatically wrap the text of the Button/Label to remain within this area.

The padding_x is horizontal padding of the text inside the widget box. It defaults to 0. The following code has a value of 5 so that the text is not close to the right border.

### Left Alignment

```
text_size: self.size
valign: "middle"
padding_x: 5
```

## Background Colour

Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a).

This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. The default texture is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''.

```
background_color: (1, 1, 0, 1)
```

## Solution - Text Left Align & Background Colour

```
<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_color: (1, 1, 0, 1)
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
```

### Output

[image]